# Extract the type of a property in an union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I use the code below:

```
interface A {
  color: "red"
  a: string
}
interface B {
  color: "green"
  b: number
}
interface C {
  color: "blue"
  c: boolean
}

type D = A | B | C // Type is like: { color: "red" | "green" | "blue" }

declare const fakeVariable: D

type Color = typeof fakeVariable.color // Type is: "red" | "green" | "blue"
```

It works as expected. But, is it possible to automatically create the type `Color` without to declare a fake variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a [index type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
type Color = D['color']
```